# How can i rewrite this same schema which is in mongo to mySql

Tags: mysql, mongodb

How can i rewrite this same schema which is in mongo to mySql

```
    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    socketid: String,
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    room: String
});
```

Comment: Do you mean by rewrite? Do you want to create equivalent table in mysql for the above schema?

Comment: yes thats what i want

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you are expecting the MySQL create table script for the above schema. If yes, please see below.

**users** - schema name

You may need to change the schema name accordingly.

```
Create table users.user_details (
    socketid varchar(250),
    username varchar(250),
    room varchar(1000),
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
);
```

Once the table is created, you can import the JSON data (i.e. MongoDB document JSON) into it. Please refer this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html).

You can export the MongoDB collection data using [MongoDB export command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/).